# Receive sms with out running app

Tags: java-me, sms

I write an App for send/receive sms,and i want a solution for receive sms with out running the  application. That is mean it's receive sms whether running or not?
please help me!!!!
thanks anybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app can't receive any old SMS.  However, using [`PushRegistry`](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2006/jw-0417-push.html) you can make your app start up when an SMS is received on a port number on which your app is listening.